# How do you create a resizable and resize it in one go? (programmatically starting the resize)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resize, resizable

I am trying to create a resizable div at the mouse position and resize it immediately to its desired size.
My failed attempt so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/YKnfR/1/

Any ideas on how to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS *above* your #block1 selector:

```
#blocks > div
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

No need to get the resizable script involved until you want the user to resize it. Just FYI, that CSS would be clearer with a `:not` selector like this:

```
#blocks > div:not(#block1)
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

but IE doesn't support `:not`, and I'm not sure how well it degrades. That's why you need to put the first example above your #block1 selector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose my question was not very clear, what I was looking for is a way to create new resizable divs on the fly. See: jsfiddle.net/KUfTa with my current solution (push shift key while dragging a new resizable div into existence)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the desired size and width using heigth() and width():

```
$(document).mousedown(function(e){
    var block = $('<div id="new">New</div>')

    $('#blocks').append(block)
    block.css('left', e.pageX).css('top', e.pageY).resizable()

    block.height('40');
    block.width('40');
})
```

Alternatively, you can place those settings right into the css.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suppose my question was not very clear, what I was looking for is a way to create new resizable divs on the fly.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/KUfTa/ with my current solution (push shift key while dragging a new resizable div into existence)

Comment: looks great, one last thing to do would be to move and size the div if the user drags the mouse from the start into direction upper left